# Prerelease versioning in NuGet

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I am trying to create a NuGet pre-release package. Here is my NuSpec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx.Web.Mvc</id>
    <version>1.0.3-prelrelease1</version>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <owners>xxx</owners>
    <projectUrl>https://xxx</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>xxxx.</description>
    <releaseNotes>NuGet package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013 xxx</copyright>
    <tags>asmx xxx</tags>
    <dependencies>
  <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0"  />
  <dependency id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
  <dependency id="xxx" version="1.0.6"  />

    </dependencies>
 </metadata>
</package>
```

Note I am using the [SemVer](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Versioning) mechanism for the pre-release version.

However, when I build my package using:

```
PM> nuget pack Package.nuspec
```

I get:

```
nuget : Input string was not in a correct format.
At line:1 char:1
+ nuget pack Package.nuspec
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Input string wa...correct format.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

This directly refers to my having alphabetic characters in the version string.

I am using NuGet 2.2/VS2012.

How come my version string isn't being recognised?

**Update**

I've reduced the file to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <package >   <metadata>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <version>1.0.3-test1</version>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <owners>xxx</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>xxx</description>   </metadata> </package>
```

and a single file in the `~\content` folder:

- ~\content\New Journal Document.jnt

(First time I've seen Windows Journal. Thought I'd try it to make a simple file. :/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

Despite reinstalling NuGet 2.x, it seems I still have a v1.5 hanging around.

Seems the Powershell environment was using this version and the `Package Manager Console Host Version 2.7.40911.225` message didn't refer to the version of PowerShell, just the host. Seems obvious now I know.

I've manhandled the file and overwritten it.

All now working.

Comment: That is what my "voidtools.com" comment/suggestion was about.  That there was an old version hanging out somewhere.

Comment: Alas, I work somewhere that is locked down. A DIR /S found it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

So both this:

```
NuGet.exe" pack ".\MyPackage.nuspec" -Version 1.0.1-alpha
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>MyCoolPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.1-alpha</version>
    <authors>MyAuthors</authors>
    <owners>MyOwner</owners>
    <!-- <licenseUrl>http://www.yourLicenseUrl.com</licenseUrl>  -->
    <projectUrl>http://www.yourProjectUrl</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://www.yourIconUrl.com</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>BuildDate : 2013_10_16__17:13:46</description>
    <releaseNotes>My Release Notes.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
    <tags>MyTag1 MyTag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <!--
            <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
            -->
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

worked for me.

I am using 2.7.40809.172.

So try:

( Number 1 )

take out your

```
<dependencies>
```

(just for kicks)

( Number 2  )

~try a later version of

```
NuGet.exe
```

(although based on the documentation, you should be ok)

I pulled

```
1.0.1-alpha
```

straight from the documentation.

Start with that, then work your way up to your custom value.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning

So I took your nuspec , and put it in my demo code.

and it worked!  (I'm xml updating the description, fyi, thus the small discrepancy) (see xml below)

But I got a nice "xxx.Web.Mvc.1.0.3-prelrelease1.nupkg" file created.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx.Web.Mvc</id>
    <version>1.0.3-prelrelease1</version>
    <authors>xxx</authors>
    <owners>xxx</owners>
    <projectUrl>https://xxx</projectUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>BuildDate : 2013_10_17__11:29:15</description>
    <releaseNotes>NuGet package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013 xxx</copyright>
    <tags>asmx xxx</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.30506.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.30506.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.30506.0" />
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

So maybe it has something to do with the "contents", not the spec.

So you can do a "basic" package, like:

```
.\Package.nuspec
.\content\
.\content\SomeImageFile.png
.\lib\
.\lib\net20\SomeDll.dll
```

and see if that works with your nuspec file with the pre-release versioning?

Comment: Thanks :) I've tried both (1) and (2) and am now running on NuGet 2.7. I still get the same error with and without the -Version flag. Also, I was looking at the same documentation. Something is awry ...

Comment: Did you try (temporarily) removing your <dependencies> entries? (for kicks)

Comment: Did you try replacing "prelrelease1" with "alpha", maybe it does not like that trailing "1" at the end of "prelrelease1" ?

Comment: Yes, I did try removing the dependencies section. Also, tried a different nuspec file without the dependencies section.

I also tried variants of the prerelease tag, including alpha, etc. as suggested in the docs - with and without numbers.

But no luck ...

Comment: I appended my response.

Comment: Thanks for staying with this one. I updated my question with a very basic XML file structure ... still falls over as soon as I add the prerelease version info.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  One last hail-mary.  Go get this tool: http://www.voidtools.com/  (which is good to have for many things).  Do a search for "NuGet.exe", and rename or remove all them except the latest-greatest one.........just to make sure..........   This one is weird dude.

Comment: And you could try another machine........since you can copy/paste a small directory.....and run the nuget.exe command line.  Again, a hail mary that "its your machine".............

Comment: I tried another machine, works fine! Frustrating. Just a `nuget pack Package.nuspec`, nothing special. Just tried downloading the command line tool again and running in its own shell, and still no luck.